# Characteristic polynomial of a Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, superconductivity, linear-algebra

In fact, this problem is more likely to be a math problem.

When I read a paper(http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2875), the author includes the characteristic polynomial for a type of matrix $A_k$ with eigenvalues $E_k$.

The characteristic polynomial is expressed as
\begin{equation}
\rho(E_k) = E_k^4 - (\text{Tr}\{A_k\})E_k^3 
+ \{\frac{1}{2}[|A_k-I| + |A_k+I|] - 1 - \text{det}A_k\}E_k^2 \notag\\
+ \frac{1}{2}[|A_k-I| - |A_k+I|]E_k +  \text{det}A_k = 0,
\end{equation}
while the matrix  $A_k$  related here is
\begin{equation}
A_k=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\xi_k - \vec{\sigma}*(\vec{V}-\vec{g}_k)
& i*(d_0+\vec{d}*\vec{\sigma})*\sigma_y\\
[i*(d_0+\vec{d}*\vec{\sigma})*\sigma_y]^\dagger
&-\xi_k + \vec{\sigma}^T*(\vec{V}+\vec{g}_k)
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation}
Here, $\vec{\sigma}=(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$, $\xi_k=\frac{k^2}{2m}-\mu$, $\sigma_i$ are Pauli matrix. $\vec{g}_k$ is a vector satisfy $\vec{g}_k=-\vec{g}_{-k}$.

Sometime $A_k$ is also called the Bogoliubov-de Gennes(BdG) Hamiltonian.

My question here is how can we deduce the characteristic polynomial $\rho(E_k)$.

Comment: I think you'll likely find that the first equation is simply a  version of the general expansion of a fourth degree monic polynomial $\prod\limits_{k=1}^4(\lambda-\lambda_k)$ - for example, the co-efficient of $\lambda^3$ is simply $-\sum\lambda_k$, equal to $\mathrm{Tr}(A)$ and so forth and you're making use of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic equation for a $N\times N$ matrix is:

$$\text{det}(A_k-\lambda I)=0$$
It is (more or less) obvious that this can be rewritten as
$$\rho(\lambda)=\prod_{k=1}^N (E_k-\lambda)=0$$

where $E_k$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix. Note that your particular notation is a little confusing because $E_k$ seems to imply that there are multiple equations here, while the standard notation (using $\lambda$ for your $E_k$ ) avoids this confusion.
The characteristic equation can quite simply be rewritten to the form that you cite.

This is all explained at length in the relevant [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Properties), which also contains a general formula for $N\times N$ matrices (the $N=4$ case is what you are dealing with). Furthermore, a generic textbook on linear algebra (such as the one cited by the authors of your article) will probably show this too.